# Laravel, how to do conditional where clause in query scopes

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table called `jobs` and `addresses`, they have a one-to-one polymorphic relationship. In the `jobs` table there is a column `has_office` this column indicates whether a job needs an address or not.

I need to make a query scope that can query only the valid jobs with `Job::valid()`. Valid in the sense that if the job has `has_office` set to true then it needs to have an address instance in the `addresses` table to be valid. however, if it's false then an address is not required.

If tried this:

```
public function address()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Address::class, 'addressable');
}

//QUERY SCOPES 

public function scopeValid()
{
    return $this->has('address');
}
```

but it doesn't work the way I wanted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify your scopeValid() query scope to handle the polymorphic relationship between the jobs and addresses table as follows:

```
public function scopeValid($query)
{
    return $query->where(function ($query) {
        //jobs that don't require address
        $query->where('has_office', false)
              ->orWhereHasMorph('addressable', '*', function ($query, $type) {
                    //jobs that require address and have an address instance.
                    $query->where('addressable_type', $type)
                          ->has('address');
              });
    });
}
```